# Creating a Mono from certain elements of a Flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to create a Mono from elements of a Flux. This mono will need to contain a certain number of elements.

I found a solution, which is use the Mono.create method, the takeUntil and onCancel method of flux.

```
private <T> void create(MonoSink<Map<String, Optional<T>>> monoSink,
                            Flux<Map<String, Optional<T>>> flux,
                            List<String> queryParams) {
        Map<String, Optional<T>> result = new HashMap<>();
        flux
                .doOnNext(g -> result.putAll(subset(g, queryParams)))
                .doOnCancel(() -> monoSink.success(result))
                .takeUntil(f -> result.keySet().containsAll(queryParams))
                .subscribe();
    }
```

Then I call it in :

```
Mono.create(monoSink -> create(monoSink, flux, params))
```

The flux is shared so it doesn't really get cancelled when we call the takeUntil.

Is it a bad practice?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case is a *reduction* operation with twist: you only want to consume input stream partially. In such case, I think the simple and sane (for publisher lifecycle) solution is to use [scanWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#scanWith-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiFunction-) operator:

1. As with reduction, it allow to aggregate/accumulate flow elements one by one
2. But, contrary to reduction, it returns a flux of intermediate state for  each accumulated element.

Combined with `takeUntil` + `last()`, it should provide what you need:

```java
public Mono<Map<String, T>> extractParameters(Flux<Map<String, T>> flux, List<String> queryParams) {
       return flux
           .scanWith(HashMap::new, 
                     result, g -> {
                         result.putAll(subset(g, queryParams));
                         return result;
                     })
           .takeUntil(result -> result.keySet().containsAll(queryParams))
           .last();
}
```